# Focus 2003 engine stalling while accelerating

Tags: ford, stall, focus

my 2003 ford focus has a problem where the engine shudders and shuts off when while driving, especially when pressing the accelerator pedal hard. If the engine stalls, it often roll starts itself back up (like a manual transmission car does , mine is automatic.) I changed the fuel pump twice, and there is no check engine light. My guess is there is a loose electrical connection or relay to something critical, or perhaps a bad camshaft sensor . I don't think a spark plug or injector is the issue because it does not have the rumbling feeling of a single cylinder problem and the whole engine shuts off while driving.   the multifunction warning light comes on.

Comment: Plugged catylic converter can also cause this. But the quickest way to start a diagnosis is to have the codes read at a parts store for free and post them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative battery terminal was damaged. There was poor grounding, which did not lead to complete loss of power in the car, but was enough to stall the engine.. The car is working fine after replacing the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Multifunction warning light comes on?  It's likely your battery is going bad.  Have it checked (along with your alternator) at an auto parts store or by a mechanic.

Comment: the negative battery terminal was damaged, so the grounding was bad. I replaced the terminal and the car seems to be working fine

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for following up with the resolution to this issue.